Are the people and the events in the book of Esther accepted as historically true?
Recently I have revisited the book of Esther and have learned more about the power struggle between Haman and Mordechai and the events that prevented the annihilation of the Jews back then. The account is full of political intrigue at the court of King Ahasueros and how Esther was prepared to die rather than see her people destroyed.
Personally, I believe that the people and the events described in the book of Esther are factual, but I would like to know if there is reliable historical evidence of this. I would also like to learn more about the celebration of Purim.
I have come to this site where I believe I will get unbiased and trustworthy sources to establish the truth of the book of Esther.

https://seforimblog.com/2013/02/identifying-achashverosh-and-esther-in/

Accepted by whom? What kind of historical evidence are you looking for?

Specifically, historical evidence accepted in Judaism and backed up by secular sources.  The link you give looks promising!

I don't know what that means. Judaism doesn't accept or not accept historical evidence. Evidence is evidence. People can interpret it however they want.

This would be an interesting question for the History SE.

@Yehuda Perhaps, but I was hoping that the Judaism site would already have historical evidence that supports the written account. I could, for example, go to Wikipedia, but I wanted to go directly to the people who already believe in Torah and the written word of G-d.

@DoubleAA -I genuinely want to know if the events in the book of Esther are accepted as historical fact. I thought if I came to the Judaism site I would get a straight answer to a straight question. Secular sources can be helpful in verifying events and characters but if I want to know about Christianity, I prefer to go to reliable Christian sources and if I want to know about Judaism, I prefer to go to reliable Judaic sources.

@Lesley Accepted by whom?? Most religious Jews probably accept it as historical fact without having looked into it at all. Is that what you want to know?

@DoubleAA Accepted by religious Jews and Christians who look into history to find evidence that supports what they believe.

@Lesley religious Jews believe the story was recorded by the main characters - Esther and Mordechai

The Talmud, Bava Batra 15a, says that the Book of Esther was written by the Men of the Great Assembly, based on a text by Mordecai.
